# How to return an ArrayList from a database query?

Tags: java, jaxb, jersey, jax-rs

I am querying a database for a web service using the Jersey JAX-RS. I can return a single row as XML or JSON, but I can't figure out how to return multiple records.

Do I use an `ArrayList`? If so how? Does anyone have an example of how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create a `RowHolder` class that defines all the fields from the table
2. Annotate the `RowHolder` with `@XmlType`
3. Use a `List<RowHolder>` with `@XmlElement` on it.

How to get the date in the `List<RowHolder>` -

```
List<RowHolder> list = new LinkedList<RowHolder>();

while (rs.next())  {
    RowHolder holder = new RowHolder();
    holder.setName(rs.get("name"));
    holder.setSurname(rs.get("surname"));
    holder.setEmail(rs.get("email"));
    // etc. for all the relevant fields
    list.add(holder);
}
```

Comment: Yes, but I need to use JAXB so Jersey can output it as XML or JSON.

Comment: Can you post an example of this?

Comment: of which? of trasnferring the `ResultSet` to a `RowHolder`? That's straightofward - just call `holder.setName(rs.get(1))`; etc.